# Correct way to get the duration between a time strings and current time in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, duration, localtime

What is the correct and easiest way to get the duration between a time string and actual time in Kotlin?

I have following time strings (timeStr): "18:00:00"
At the end I like to have a string like this: "x hours and y minutes to ..."

My current solution:

```
val diff: Long = (LocalTime.parse(timeStr).toSecondOfDay() - LocalTime.now().toSecondOfDay()).toLong()
val duration: LocalTime = LocalTime.ofSecondOfDay(diff)
outStr = duration.hour + "hours and " + duration.minute + " minutes to ..."
```

I am aware that the solution is error prone, so I am looking for a clean solution. I have only recently started using Kotlin and am not yet familiar with the possibilities.

Comment: FYI, you could use `Duration.between(parsedTime, now)`. But I think there are even better Kotlin extensions with Kotlin's Duration instead of Java's.

Comment: A `LocalTime` is for a time of day, not for a difference. You need one of the `Duration` classes, as @Joffrey mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you use [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) which is modelled on [ISO-8601 standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and was introduced with *Java-8* as part of [JSR-310 implementation](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/pfd/jsr310/JSR-310-guide.html). With *Java-9* some more convenience methods were introduced.

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Duration duration = Duration.between(LocalTime.now(), LocalTime.parse("18:00:00"));
        // Default format
        System.out.println(duration);

        // Custom format
        // ####################################Java-8####################################
        String formattedDuration = String.format("%d hour(s) and %d minute(s)", duration.toHours(),
                duration.toMinutes() % 60);
        System.out.println(formattedDuration);
        // ##############################################################################

        // ####################################Java-9####################################
        formattedDuration = String.format("%d hour(s) and %d minute(s)", duration.toHoursPart(),
                duration.toMinutesPart());
        System.out.println(formattedDuration);
        // ##############################################################################
    }
}
```

**Output from a sample run:**

```
PT47M23.239687S
0 hour(s) and 47 minute(s)
0 hour(s) and 47 minute(s)
```

#### [Online Demo](https://ideone.com/u9MxWS)

Learn about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 2):

As "Anonymous" commented, you can use the `Duration` classes for this:

```
fun getDuration(timeStr: String): String {
    val time = LocalTime.parse(timeStr)
    val now = LocalTime.now()
    val duration = Duration.between(now, time)
    val hours = duration.toHours()
    val minutes = duration.minusHours(hours).toMinutes()
    return if (hours == 0L) {
        "$minutes minutes to ..."
    } else if (minutes == 0L) {
        "$hours hours to ..."
    } else {
        "$hours hours and $minutes minutes to ..."
    }
}
```